# Youtube API get a video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a simple thing - a video, and i just can't understand why such a simple thing, is not clearly defined in the API docs.

To search for a video i have :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=guy&key=api key
```

Than , i get the json, with results like :

```
    "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
     "etag": "\"MmqJLb8ZBOWRQIsg7xej7lrKLMI/_yCHjN-Yei6to4bLpd2j603Ea18\"",
     "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
     "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 223929,
      "resultsPerPage": 5

 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"MmqJLb8ZBOWRQIsg7xej7lrKLMI/ruSBEQPUZp3DX2M8M4bcCPny2fc\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "J0tGubH9ZyM"
   },
```

What should i do now, to retrieve this first video ? i just need to get the link to the video with the video id, (or etag ? )
How the next request should look like ?

Comment: 1) what language you use ? 2) what informations you want about the video ?. We can't help you without this 2 points.

Comment: 3) Also post us your code with the request to the API

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all you want is a URL for the video (at youtube's page), it takes this form:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={videoId}

If you're instead looking to embed the video on your page, you could either do so with the embed code, which you can get with this call:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=player&id={videoId}&key=api key

Or with the iFrame API, which you can read about here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: thanks, i am using iOS , my goal is to stream the video to my own player. is that the second code ?

Comment: If you issue the second call, you'll get the <iframe> code that you can embed in a web app. If you want to instead play the video in a native iOS application, then you can use this library: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper ... it will let you create a YTPlayerView and load in the video by referencing the videoId. IF you are saying you want to get access to the direct video stream, and play that with player code you've written yourself, then that isn't possible; YouTube only allows the playing of videos through one of their many players.

Comment: thanks that worked. but why they dont let you to get on the search results, also the embedded url? the first api request gives you a json anyway,why not include there just another line with the embedded link ? is there a way to get it in one call ?